# Code timing comparison between 2 databases

Tags: java, oracle

We have a Java project with an Oracle DB.

I made a big change in my code that includes a scheme change, in order to reduce the time for some operations.

For this purpose, I made a local DB rather than the shared team DB.

I started to measure the time (my code with my DB vs the original code with the shared DB) and I found out that the timing got worse.

I used a profiler and I found that there are some places that the difference is in the "read" function -

[image: new DB]

[image: old DB]

as you can see, it's 2.715 vs 0.514 - 5.3 times greater.

I read that the difference between the DBs can cause this time difference.

1. Is that true? Can it cause this big difference?
2. Except for changing the scheme every time, is there any other option of comparison?

Thx

Comment: Its socket inputstrem read time so its network latency + db internal operations.

Comment: In order to compare the time taken for an operation, one would need to at least have the same machine specifications and/or same DB configs for the different databases to achieve a valid baseline.(Assuming the shared team DB and Local DB are on different machines)

Comment: Indeed it's different machines. I have the old and new code in my machine but the DBs are on different machines so I thought maybe there is a workaround for this compare...

Comment: @Antoniossss - good point. I just checked the ping to the new DB macine and it gave me less than 1ms..

Comment: You can't profile 2 different databases through a Java profiler. The results will be meaningless numbers, because of the differences in hardware, configuration etc. you'd have to at least use the same server. You also need to make sure the profiler profiles the same actions, otherwise you again have 2 meaningless unrelated numbers.

Comment: @Kayaman I have 2 Tomcats on my machine due to the code difference. The main difference is in my code except for the scheme difference. and about the action, I checked the exact same function so for that point I think I'm good... anyways I know that it's not optimal but I thought that because it should be a common case maybe there is a workaround for this.

Comment: There's no workaround. You have to do things properly when profiling. The tiniest things can skew the results, so your approach is about as good as throwing a dice and letting that indicate the performance.

Comment: I was worried that this will be the answer... I will see what I can do... thx anyway! you helped me a lot! all of you!

Comment: It seems you are asking us to comment on the possible impact of making a "big change" to your code including a "scheme change". But you haven't provided any details of the change you've made or even hinted at what you've done. Obviously it is possible to change a database in a way with degrades its performance. Maybe this is what you have done. But unless you give us some more information there's no way we can give you any meaningful advice.

Comment: @APC - you're absolutely right. but the changes that I made, besides the scheme changes, are part of the company's logic and business so I'm not sure if it'll help you. My main problem is a general problem cause the measuring should take time and the code only won't help you...